# BATCH to get a specific string from a txt file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, text-files

I would like to set a parameter that I can find in a txt file. 
This is a specific string, it's found in the first row after the character "=".

Example: description.txt

```
card=0123456789
status=false
```

I should take the string "0123456789" and set the parameter %str%.
I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%a in ('type C:\tmp\description.txt^|find "card="') do (
set str=%%a & goto :continue
)
:continue
echo %str%

pause
```

how can I get the text after "=" in the first row?

TIA

//khs

Comment: Perhaps you should change your `delims=<space>` to the real delimiter, in your case an equal sign. `delims==`

Comment: OH great! Thank you

Comment: Why do you use `find "card="` if the data you want "_it's found in **the first** row_" ?  **`:(`**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the delims like this `"delims=="`

```bat
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('type "C:\tmp\description.txt" ^|findstr /bi "card="') do (
    set "str=%%a" & goto :continue
)
:continue
echo "%str%"
pause
```

Comment: it's more secure to use `findstr /bi "card="` (in case there are lines like `Mastercard=` or `cardnumber`)

Comment: @Stephan Yep i edited my answer refer to your comment ! Thank you for the clever remark man !

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('type C:\tmp\description.txt' | find "card"') do echo %%a
```

An extra delimiter `=` is definitely needed. Otherwise, it will not work.

Comment: yes, because you want to split at the `=`. But for what reason do you split at spaces too? (that could be fatal in some situations)

Comment: Sorry, it was a typing mistake.